# Is there any way I can log network calls been triggered from the App

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am developing an Android SDK/library, In here I am performing several network calls. This SDK belong to **developer tool** category.

In more details, what I wanted to say, if the application developer adds our SDK to their project so we can get the network log during selected period when user wants to save the network log.

I want to know if this is possible to do because it kind of breaching the network thing, but whoever uses our SDK knows that this SDK has a feature that can help with capturing network log.